# Acronyms in headers/lists - small caps?

Tags: typography

I am doing my resume right now, and I have a **lot** of acronyms. I'm using an OpenType font, so I've always put those acronyms in small caps. I've never quite been sure what to do, though, when a heading line or a list item begins with an acronym. When it begins with any other word, I would capitalize that first word. But with an acronym that's set in small caps, do I bump the first letter up to regular caps? Looks weird, to my eye.

Small caps alone

[image: Small caps alone]

Small caps with full caps

[image: Small caps with full caps]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Butterick's guide to typography is my go-to typographical reference, here's [what it says](https://practicaltypography.com/small-caps.html) on the matter:

> With small caps, it’s your call whether to use reg­u­lar cap­i­tal
>   let­ters at the be­gin­ning of cap­i­tal­ized words. I pre­fer not to.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of preference....

For Acronyms I would use all uppercase. Small caps is fine if mid sentence and the *entire* acronym is small caps.

However, starting a sentence or section should be all caps for acronyms. There should *not* be any visual variance in the size of the glyphs in an acronym, ever. That kind of defeats the acronym itself.

Comment: `There should not be any visual variance in the size of the glyphs in an acronym, ever. That kind of defeats the acronym itself.`  

Thank you for putting that into words. That's really been my hangup with this, I think.

Comment: It is a difficult call. I kind of agree with you, with the reservation that visual variance is acceptable in certain pronounceable acronyms, like NATO.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read any hard-and-fast rules and seems to come down to personal preference in much of the reading I've done on this. A key factor is being consistent, choosing a typeface with small caps, and applying proper letterspacing.

Some suggest rewording a sentence so it doesn't need to start with an acronym but that seems an unlikely approach in formatting a list of technical skills on your resume. In prose that's more easily done.

Refer to http://theworldsgreatestbook.com/book-design-part-5/ (the "Book Design Tip: Use Small Caps to represent Characters in a Play", and "Book Design Tip: Use Small Caps for Elegant Headlines" sections). There, I think the mixing of full cap with small caps works quite well.

---

[image: Capitals in plays]

---

[image: Capitals in headlines]

---

As the convention for sentences is to begin with a capital, our eyes are trained for this and so I think full cap/small cap mixing is perfectly acceptable and more visually pleasing at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Your examples are ordinary words, but his main concern is about acronyms. I found this question exactly because I have similar concerns. I kind of agree with Scott that there should not be visual variance in the size of the glyphs in an acronym.